# Can't set valid charset for gift card prizes JSON output

Tags: php, json, content-type

I'm getting a strange error with outputting JSON with php:

> Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.[Code 29,
>   Structure 0]

I've tried adding this to the header as follows but so far no luck:

```
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

Returned from this tool: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

The JSON feed is located here:

https://www.pointsprizes.com/api/mobile/account/prizes/123132

Tried everything I can think of, tried setting it to 16 then 32 and still no luck. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I'll remove the charset=utf-8 setting, so you can see what is being output

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Now all my users can see their free gift cards prizes from the API :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amy check this response:

```
{"status":"success","reason":"","device":"","version":"","email":"john.smith@gmail.com","id":"123132","points":"1502","offers":"true","hyprmx":"true","prizes":"true","visit":"true","html":"<!doctype html><html lang='en'><head></head><body><p style='font-weight:900;'>received account_id: 123132</p><p>received device: </p><p>received version: </p></body></html>"}
```

HTMl is also present in this:

```
<!doctype html><html lang='en'><head></head><body><p style='font-weight:900;'>received account_id: 123132</p><p>received device: </p><p>received version: </p></body></html>
```

because of this html, with `json_decode()` it is showing:

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'en' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

When I remove it and `json_decode()` it, it is giving:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => success
    [reason] => 
    [device] => 
    [version] => 
    [email] => john.smith@gmail.com
    [id] => 123132
    [points] => 1502
    [offers] => true
    [hyprmx] => true
    [prizes] => true
    [visit] => true
    [html] => 
)
```

Comment: Check this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3675041fa2c7ccc29c2d61a861a69c1f2d9d1a6

Comment: The issue is here: lang='en'. Here string is not properly concatenated.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to run this through json_encode() with the concatenation fixed and see if hit helps..

Comment: Ya, the issue is because of string concatenation.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I'm just uploading the change. I think it is still producing error ;(

Comment: Maybe the charset isn't utf-8?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136945/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-amy-neville).